# Packages that are not updated when running meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I alter some code in a package at

```
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\accounts-ui-unstyled\1.3.0\web.browser\login_buttons.js
```

The thing is , after I alter the code and run “meteor” in the command line the changes are not implemented, I even deleted the whole package mentioned before and run the app and it was like … nothing happened, it’s like the application have some sort of a cache of the packages that he doesn’t have to go to that path to get them , instead it uses what it had from it before.
Can anyone please explain this to me ? What’s happening here ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of "changing" a package is to `git clone` the package from git (or otherwise retrieve it's source) into either a project internal `/packages` folder or a project external folder (requires [environment variable](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#METEOR-PACKAGE-DIRS) `METOER_PACKAGE_DIRS`).

If the package is, as in your case, a Meteor internal package, you can also copy only the package into your project and even add it to your versioning.

In this package you then apply your changes. It will be used in favor of the atmosphere package.

A good practice is to also increment the package version, so it is known for everyone that a custom version is in use.

**Why you should not change packages inside the users `\Users\...\.meteor` installation packages folder?**

This is the path to packages, that will be used as defaults for every new meteor project you create. Deep changes can create deep damage to your projects since changing a package will apply to all dependent projects.

Think also about project specific customization. The above described method will allow this, too.

Comment: I have created the "/packages" folder in the folder of the app and placed "\accounts-ui-unstyled" inside and still the changes have not been updated.

Comment: changing the package in packages folder works for me all the time, you might try `meteor reset` or try `meteor remove THE_PACKAGE` then `meteor add THE_PACKAGE`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that you also can explicitly set the package version via `packagexyz@x.y.z` in the meteor packages file.